# Render multiple actions (with views) in Yii

Tags: view, yii, render

I'm used to working with Zend Framework where I can do a partial render. In this render, the according action is called and I get the output from the render.

Now, Is there a way to do something like this with YII too?
I'm making a request to a controller/action which is the report of several calculations. Since the combination of calculations isn't the same for every report, I created a controller for each calculation. Every controller has an action, called report where the calculations are being done. This report action uses data from the database. Is there a way to generate a page with multiple views? (one for every calculation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have one controller function in which it has called to different function to get the various calculations to get the data, then parse this to the template where you can then parse these into partials.

In controller

```
public function actionCal()
{    
     $data = array();
     $data['finance'] = $this->financeCal();
     $data['holiday'] = $this->holidayCal();                            
     $this->render('calculation', array('data'=>$data));
}
```

In view

```
    <?php $this->renderPartial('//cal/_finance_summary', array('financeData'=>$data['finance'])); ?>
    <?php $this->renderPartial('//cal/_holioday_summary', array('holidayData'=>$data['holiday'])); ?>
```

Comment: Interesting. Do the different calculations are in the same controller in your example code? Can I have them in multiple controllers? How?

Comment: Yes you could write reusable functions which could be used by multiple controllers. For instance a new action could also call $this->holidayCal(); to get the required information for that controller.

Comment: I did some rethinking on my problem and I think the calculations should go in the model. Not in an action of the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You have renderPartial in Yii as well, so this should not be a problem. Just structure your methods (actions) in a way that allow you to reuse them. PS: The 3rd param to renderPartial enables you to get the output returned instead of printed.

Comment: I tried it with the renderPartial from Yii, but it seems I don't go through the action. The app will only show me the rendered view without processing the action. Or am I wrong? (Please tell me I'm wrong, so my problem is solved :-p )

Answer (score 0):

I have just added a `public property $data` to my base Controller class. Then in each action I use `$this->data` to send variables to views. And if I need to render some view file from another view file, I also use `$this->data`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Yii widgets for this purpose.